# Getting attributes from same-named XDocument elements using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, attributes, linq-to-xml

I've been coding a program that stores employee data using XDocument:

```
<!-- School Employee Data -->
<SchoolData storeName="mikveIsrael" location="mikve">
    <employee id="1">
        <personalInfo>
            <name>Ilan Berlinbluv</name>
            <zip>58505</zip>
        </personalInfo>
        <employeeInfo>
            <salary>5000</salary>
            <id>1</id>
        </employeeInfo>
    </employee>
    <employee id="2">...</employee>
</SchoolData>
```

I want my program to read every `employee` `id` attrib, but I don't know how to do so. Instead, I tried doing this:

```
    var ids = from idz in doc.Descendants("SchoolData")
              select new
              {
                  id1 = idz.Element("employee").Attribute("id").Value
              };
```

where `doc` is the XDocument var. It returns just the first one, but I want it to return an `array` or `List<string>`, I just don't know how to iterate through all the same-named `employee` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
List<string> ids = doc.Descendants("employee")
                        .Select(e => e.Attribute("id").Value)
                          .ToList();
```

Comment: Can you explain please?

Comment: it'll find every node named `employee` and grab the attribute value of it, and return a list

Answer (score 1):

This may helps:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(path);

var result = xDoc.Descendants("employee")
                 .SelectMany(i => i.Attribute("id").Value)
                 .ToList();
```